# How can you make a div not affected by css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make a portion of code not be affected by css?

I have some images that have no border and want them to stay like that.
When I copy the code to someone else's website their css seems to override what I set them to do. Is there anyway to make a block of code not affected by the outside? Thank you

Comment: If you are just copying images then no. Perhaps a 'phone call to the owner of the web site might be more fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

Put your styles inline. These will take precedence over style in style sheets or in the head of the page.

For example...

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" style="border:none">
```

You can also add the `!important` tag to a style to make it take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the site's stylesheets then you can't exactly disable styles on a tag-by-tag basis. However, you can override them with inline styles, for example:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" style="..." />
```

Replace the `...` with whatever style you want to enforce in your image, and it will take precedence over the site's stylesheets. The challenge is that you need to make sure you override everything relevant. Anything missed-out will fall-back to the site's stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you could move your styles inline, or you could display your content on their site in an iframe - but obviously that has other implications so it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not(.className)` in the CSS to exclude a certain div from rendering that CSS.